# Java "press button" with different actions each time pressed

Tags: java, object, user-interface, button

I would like to program a small score counter. I have implemented two buttons that only return one thing when pressed. I want a new score to appear every time is pressed.

The following shows the code I already written:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    
    
    JButton button;
    JButton button2;
    
    int clicked1Count = 0;
    int clicked2Count = 0;
    
    
    
Thank you in advance.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make 2 variables as in

```
clicked1Count = 0
clicked2Count = 0
```

And in your action performed increase the counter as per your need.
And print it after that

```
if (ae.getSource()==button){
    clicked1Count++;
}
else if (ae.getSource()==button2) {
    clicked2Count++;
}
```

Comment: instead of++, just do clicked1Count += 15; and clicked2Count += 15;

Comment: And how should i do it from 30 to 40 - for example player1 does 2 points -> 30:0 and then he does one more point, so his score is 40:0 now

Comment: Just have a check if the count is 30 and then during that only increment 10.

Comment: That does not work if i click button 1 three times without clicking button 2 one time - check the code please - i updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your underlying *design* is basically nonexistent. If you don't spend considerable time to think *upfront* how to *model* the things you want to work with, you will always end up with overly complicated spaghetti code.

As in:

- put the "amount to increment" into an array. Then your clickCount is used as index in that array.
- go with *one* listener *per* button.
- instead of working with raw int values that hold your values, introduce a class like `Player` that has a `setScore` method. Or even more OOP: the player class gets a method `increaseScore()`. And that method **isolates** the knowledge how the score gets increased.

In other words: create helpful abstractions. That is what makes up good OOP. Instead of trying to stuff all code for everything into one action listener.